# CNAME address in apache configuration

Tags: apache

I have MULTIPLE domain to map my server's subdomain. For example

```
www.xyz.com -> goo.myserverdomain.com
www.lmn.com -> fb.myserverdomain.com
www.abc.com -> twt.myserverdomain.com
```

I do the mapping using CNAME in each domain. Now at my server end, I want to resolve my server subdomain. So i want to configure like

```
ServerName myserverdomain.com
ServerAlias *.myserverdomain.com
ProxyPass / http://<IP>:8780/(goo/fb/twt ...)
```

When I do the configuration, apache do not recognize the virtual host and show the first default one. I seems that i am getting host name. How to resolve myserverdomain address in my configuration. Please help

Comment: please post your actual Virtual Host Directive

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how the domain mapping is done. Apache does not know this and also the web browser does not care. It simply reacts on the line "Host:" send in header.

To enable virtual name solving, you need to set

```
NameVirtualHost ...
```

for each IP+port combination or with '*' for all.

Usually when starting, Apache will tell you that you have virtual hosts, but no proper name switching.

Comment: As of Apache 2.4 NameVirtualHost is no longer needed. [Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html)

Comment: Nice to know (for the future :-)